Permit and swap in one TX
Hello I am trying to make a Python code using web3.
The objective is making "ONE" transaction which can permit and swap.
I tried 'multicall' which have two calls:

permit (caller: multicall contract, owner: EOA, sender: swap router)
swap (caller: multicall contract)

Since swap caller is multicall contract who does not have approval or permit, transferFrom failed.
Is there another method to achieve my goal?
Thank you.

can you share the code of the router?

You can see the Uniswap Universal Router here
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad
